# Change tint of textView compound drawable in app widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a widget with a layout containing a `TextView`.

```
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/appwidget_soc"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/md_keylines"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/md_keylines"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_battery_charging"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/connected_textView"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />
```

I want to change both the text color and the drawable color as well, but I cannot seem to find out how to do that from the context of an `AppWidgetProvider`

Answer (score -1):

Compound drawable is not going to work in RemoteViews. You will need to split TextView and ImageView in your layout.